# Get the xml representation of a Solr Schema with Solrj SchemaRequest

Tags: java, scala, solr, playframework, solrj

I want to get my Schema in an XML format with the SchemaRequest class of SolrJ. According to the [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html#SchemaAPI-RetrievetheEntireSchema) it should be with the query parameter wt=xml but it doesn't matter how I send it, It always returns the response in json format. Is it possible to get the schema using SolrJ in an xml format as described in the docs?

this is what I'm doing right now:

```
val client =       new HttpSolrClient.Builder().withBaseSolrUrl(s"http://$host:$port/solr$collectionPath").build
val solrParams       = new ModifiableSolrParams(params)
val getSchemaRequest = new SchemaRequest(solrParams)
getSchemaRequest.process(client).getResponse
```

The last line is the one that gives me the proper schema but in json format. Thanks in advance.

I tried to add to add the XMLResponseParser as suggested in the comments.

```
val getSchemaRequest = new SchemaRequest(query)
getSchemaRequest.setResponseParser(new XMLResponseParser)
```

but now I'm getting this exception:

```
class org.apache.solr.common.util.SimpleOrderedMap cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (org.apache.solr.common.util.SimpleOrderedMap is in unnamed module of loader play.runsupport.NamedURLClassLoader @150d015c; java.util.Map is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Comment: not sure about the solrj api...but can you try the json to xml converstion

Comment: try setting solr.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_4_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrRequest.html#setResponseParser-org.apache.solr.client.solrj.ResponseParser-